# Borel codes and forcing

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, borel-sets, forcing

Can someone recommend to me some papers or books to learn about coding Borel sets and its absoluteness between transitive models (specially such generated by forcing)?

I was reading a paper about Rendom and Cohen reals which touch this topic (Written by Kunen in the handbook of set theoretic topology). However I found it somehow loose.

I appreciate any recommendation which you can share with me.

Comment: I learned it from relevant chapters of Kanamori (maybe, the chapter about the Solovay model.) However, you may feel Kanamori's explanation is also loose...

Comment: @HanulJeon thanks a lot. I will give to Kanamori's explanation a chance. Maybe he can bring me more light about the subject.